# My password hash is not working it runs my else code when logging in

Tags: php

Im having a problem when using password_hash in my login page when i register the password is hashed but when i login it runs the else part in my code

**here is my login code**

```
function login(){
    global $db, $username, $errors, $disable, $hashed_password;

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);


    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = password_verify($password, $hashed_password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
            if ($logged_in_user['user_status'] == 'Active') {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
            }else{
                array_push($disable, "Your Account has been disabled");
            }
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }

    }
}
```

**and here is the part where i hash the password**

```
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: The `login` function doesn't contain this line. Can you elaborate on how it is called?

Comment: You should pass the values as parameters to your login function instead of using globals.

Comment: `password_verify` returns true or false. Why do you inject that into SQL?

Comment: Im just new into PHP :'( If i change it to PDO do i need to re code all of my website or just the register and login function?

Comment: You would need to change your whole website. You can stay with MySQLi, but you should use prepared statements...see the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared statement, then fetch the hashed password from the database, and match it against the `$_POST['password']` in `password_verify()`.

Generally speaking, using `global` is discouraged - you should pass arguments to the functions instead.

```
function login(){
    global $db, $errors, $disable;

    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, password, user_status FROM users WHERE username=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $hashed_password, $user_status);

        if ($stmt->fetch() && password_verify($_POST['password'], $hashed_password)) {
            if ($user_status == 'Active') {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user_id;
            } else {
                $disable[] = "Your Account has been disabled";
            }
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Wrong username/password combination";
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but due to im new with PDO i cant find where to put `$logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);` because i cant see it to your code

Comment: PDO does not have the method `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, thats MySQLi. That said, you do not use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in that code, because its using a prepared statement - which is much better and much more secure than a normal `query()`. The function in my answer is the complete function.

Comment: how do i echo `user_type` in my DB? `$_SESSION['user'] = $user_id;` its should be right here? because i have code that it will redirect the users in their pages based on their role

Comment: You can either set a session with the username instead, i.e. `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username']` (or fetch it from the DB so you get the correct capitalization), or run a query on the page, where you use the user ID to get the username.